# Enable saving draft questions and answers

Tags: feature-request, editing, sandbox

As in the title - please, enable saving drafts of questions and drafts of answers, and returning to them on my next visit to MO.

I am very slow in putting my thoughts into print. I Leave them for some time, return or delete them later. In most cases I don't like what I wrote. Now - I have to manage my drafts with an external editor. It would be more convenient to have such a feature available within the MO.

Edit: As Andrew explains it in the comments - the feature I wanted is already present: the system automatically saves my draft once in a while. I get the draft back when I log in and return to the same question. Now I see no need for any change, thanks.

Comment: It is already implemented and is done automatically. Once in a minute may be.

Comment: @Andrew How do you get back to it when you want to complete the text some other day?

Comment: I think there are Firefox and Chrome plugins that can accomplish this for you.

Comment: @AdamPrzezdziecki going to the same question after logging in. Then writing an answer after some time words appears "draft saved".

Comment: @Andrew Great - this works. Thank you for explaining, this is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You can "save" one draft answer at a time.

If you feel that you need to keep multiple drafts at a time, you can use your email account (supposedly GMail, but anything works really). Type the answer on the page (to see it compiles with the MathJax and whatnot), then copy it to a draft email whose title is the question name/link/whatever you feel like. Save the drafts and return to them easily.

If your MathJax/LaTeX abilities are sufficient then you don't really need to compile the answers, and you can type them directly into an email draft.

Comment: This is roughly what I am doing now - I save drafts in a text file on my GoogleDrive. It is not a big work, but still it would be more convenient to just click "save as draft" whenever I realize that I have no more time today or I run out of invention.

Comment: I generally disagree with the idea that the site should save your drafts for you. Perhaps increase from one to three-four drafts and allow you to "manage them" in your profile, but it sounds like something which is essentially outside the scope of the software.

Comment: I see - I misunderstood your words >>You can "save" one draft answer at a time<<. Now, after Andrew has explained it above the present functionality, as it is, is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Adam, that's good.